# How to implement Facebook Social Login in Hybrid application?

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, hybrid-mobile-app

I was planning to use Facebook Social Login in my Hybrid application ( HTML5/CSS/JS and Cordova) However on going to facebook developer I could not see an option for choosing cordova based app.

So shall I consider www , i.e. Javascript based SDK for implementing facebook social login?

From security point of view, is it good choice to choose JS SDK in hybrid application?

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can choose **www** for create app for hybrid platform and you just need to set the App id into application so if someone decompile your app they just get an App Id and nothing else, other all things are saved into your developer facebook account.

So you can create your app with this **www** without worrying about the security of an app.

Also you can create Facebook login with the simplest use of [OpenFB](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB),

You just need to create Facebook API from [Facebook Developer Account](http://developer.facebook.com/)

And Pass the App ID into javascript file of facebook login function.